# How to use d3 zoom that olny manipulate scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement d3 zoom in my chart.

Here is a sample chart I have created to make my question more clear:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/nuegmh0a/

I went through some of the zoom tutorial in internet but none of them are quite suitable for my requirement.

I have a gantt chart that has two part. one is the navigation chart and other is the main view. The navigation chart render the chart over complete timeline.
Where as, the main view only display part of the chart that is covered by a brush in the navigation chart.

I need to implement zoom functionality that be triggered by mouse wheel and will re-size the brush extent (as re-sizing brush extent would allow user to zoom in and zoom out)

I am trying to use zoom behavior in d3, but not sure how to set it up to manipulate brush extent in zoom callback function.

Most of the zoom example I saw was utilizing translate and scale from zoom.
But I think what I need is just to manipulate brush extent.

How can I do it?

```
Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/nuegmh0a/
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/sbreslav/be9af0d809b49864b7d8)?

Comment: It helps. Thanks.
Here is my updated code.
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/a20qtj4a/4/

How ever, I am not quire sure what is the best way to restrict the brush within chart area.